# Fetching data from DB2 for more than 49 records takes more time

Tags: java, db2

I am basically comparing text file lines data with that from DB. Here are my steps:

1. Reading data from each line & saving in Array.
2. Iterate over each line from Text File & fetching data from DB2 for Unique Card Number which is present in Text file.

Problem : When I consider above comparison for 50 records then it works fine (takes only 29 seconds) and give correct result. But when I increase lines in text file (i.e. 55-60 lines in text file) then it executes but take unexpected 20 minutes.

Due to data security I can't share code.

Comment: Reconsider your design.   Line by line processing is not scalable.  Why not load/import/ingest the text file into a Db2-table (or temporary table), creating indexes as needed, and let SQL do the work of comparison.   If you cannot reconsider your design, you need to *do your own research* to find the bottleneck if you cannot share the code.  At the least you need to know how to identify where the slowdown is happening.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I appreciate that a company policy of not sharing code is not your fault, but you should tell managers who _can_ change it that it is unhelpful and counterproductive. The impact of it is that your question may be seen as too vague to answer, and if enough people agree with that, you may find that your questions are put on hold as off-topic (unclear, too broad, etc). The broad point managers need to understand is that small pieces of code are not valuable intellectual property, and can be written by any competent engineer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough real information here to give an "answer". I do agree with Mao that line-by-line processing really isn't sustainable, but that's not the cause of this aberrant behaviour.

I assume based on the relative naiveté of your approach that you are probably creating a new Connection object for each line of the file. I suspect that what's happening is that you are reaching a limit on the number of concurrent connections for your DB2 server - 50 seems like a reasonable setting for that. If you are doing this, create a single Connection object and reuse it for every line processed.

Alternatively, if you're re-using the same Connection object for all the lines, I think it's likely that the DB2 server has some unusual settings that are causing your connection to behave in an unexpected way, e.g. limit on number of operations per connection. I am not super knowledgeable about DB2 so I can't suggest any specific settings to look for. You could try to work around this by disconnecting and reconnecting every 50 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You should not iterate over each line and query DB.

Instead collect the cardNumbers in to a list and get the data from DB all at once by:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CARD_NUMBER IN (cardNumberList)
```

Comment: While that's an improvement, it'll be unworkable for a large dataset too. It's better to iterate over the data from the file in pages, maybe 50-100 lines at a time.

Comment: You have paging to back you up.

Comment: The point is to get data for multiple cardNumbers instead of getting them one by one